# How define dimensions of connector?

Tags: connector

I'm trying to define dimensions of the connector. 
And don't understand what is "No of spaces".

What does it mean "No of spaces" (highlighted)?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, please take the time to write a gramatically correct question to attract answers.

Comment: No. is abbreviation for number of spaces and there are 9 spaces between the pins to in total value of A is 9*1.27=11.43 (mm i believe)

Comment: And though we have 2 rows, its clear from the bottom right diagram in the datasheet that he is considering spaces from 1st pin to last pin. And in the top left image its mentioned that 1.27 is the distance between two adjacent pins (nearest pin, even if its in other row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the spaces between the pairs of pins. To be exact, it is equal to the number of pins minus one.

Comment: pairs of pins rather 4 to 26 pins

Comment: I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No of spaces

Here spaces between the two pin.It helps to calculate the dimensions

IF there are 1 space between pins, then the distance is 1.27
2 spaces would be 2.54
3 spaces would be 3.81, ect

Answer (score 0):

No. means the number of spaces and there are 9 spaces between the pins to in total, the value of A is 9*1.27=11.43 (mm I believe).

[More info on No.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign)

Comment: But we have two rows of pins, and there are 8 spaces between pins. Is it important that we have two rows of pins?

Comment: It's not about the importance but how the manufacturer have made the connector and the way he is communicating values in the datasheet. Probably he is trying to save some work, so that he can type the same values for multiple connectors with a different number of pins in the same package.